# Determining when Picard's theorem is applicable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$u'=\dfrac{u^\frac{1}{3}-u^2}{1+x^3}, u(0)=u_0$

For which values of $u_0$ can we apply Picard's theorem.

Now, I do have a solution for this one (provided with the problem) but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Firstly, the function $f(x,u)=\dfrac{u^\frac{1}{3}-u^2}{1+x^3}$ is continuous for every $x$ except for $-1$. Also, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ is continuous everywhere.
I would then conclude that we can apply Picard's theorem for any $u_0$. But they somehow, without explanation, rule out $u_0=0$ and then check it separately later, showing we can't
apply the theorem for that value.

I'm just starting here so I don't yet know the nuances. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: " Also, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}$ is continuous everywhere". What is everywhere exactly?

Comment: Well, everywhere the first coordinate isn't zero, I think.

Comment: Are you sure you mean the first coordinate?

Comment: Oh man! It appears I forgot how to differentiate polynomials... Thanks for the heads up...

Comment: Should this question be closed or should I just wait for someone to point out my mistake in an answer and then accept that?

Comment: More importantly, do you see why $0$ was excluded now?

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure what's the best course of action here.My *opinion* is that it is OK to delete the question.

Comment: @GitGud Yeah, I do. The exponent becomes negative after diff.